# WordPress wp-admin redirect to http://127.0.0.1/

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have this problem: when I try to login to my WP dashboard (wp-admin), it redirects to 127.0.0.1.

When I type `websitename.com/wp-admin` it show "Unable to connect".

Can anyone help?

My `.htaccess` file at the root of my site:

```
# BEGIN All In One WP Security
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_WP_FILE_ACCESS_START
<Files license.txt>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Files>
<Files wp-config-sample.php>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Files>
<Files readme.html>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_WP_FILE_ACCESS_END
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files .htaccess>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Files>
ServerSignature Off
LimitRequestBody 10240000
<Files wp-config.php>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_PINGBACK_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files xmlrpc.php>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_PINGBACK_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_DEBUG_LOG_BLOCK_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files debug.log>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_DEBUG_LOG_BLOCK_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_INDEX_VIEWS_START
Options -Indexes
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_INDEX_VIEWS_END
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_TRACE_TRACK_START
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_TRACE_TRACK_END
#AIOWPS_FORBID_PROXY_COMMENTS_START
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:FORWARDED} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:USERAGENT_VIA} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_HOST} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROXY_CONNECTION} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:XPROXY_CONNECTION} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP} !^$
RewriteRule wp-comments-post\.php - [F]
#AIOWPS_FORBID_PROXY_COMMENTS_END
#AIOWPS_ENABLE_BRUTE_FORCE_PREVENTION_START
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (wp-admin|wp-login)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(action\=postpass)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !aiowps_secret= [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !aiowps_cookie_test_kzs9w240bq= [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1 [L]
#AIOWPS_ENABLE_BRUTE_FORCE_PREVENTION_END
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_SPAMBOTS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-comments-post\.php(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://abc\.com [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
    RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1 [L]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_SPAMBOTS_END
# END All In One WP Security

# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
# DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is for development on your own machine: `RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1 [L]`

Replace the ip with your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using All In One WP Security plugin, and now have migrated to a public domain.

Consider updating the plugin's settings.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines to your `wp-config.php`, where **"example.com"** is the correct location of your site.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

#### To resolve this problem:

1. Login to phpmyadmin
2. Go to wordpress => wp_option
3. Edit *option_value* for *option_name* **siteurl** and **home** to correct location [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQNgy.png)

Answer (score 0):

websitename.com/wp-admin it show "Unable to connect".

Please check your site theme settings to 
Remove the WordPress version meta tag from your website.

Comment: [Comments posted as an answer are subject to removal.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Answer (score -1):

You problem will be solved using this code. I give guarantee. Thanks for happy coding.

add_filter( 'init', "set_cookie_func" );

function set_cookie_func(){

$secure = ( 'https' === parse_url( wp_login_url(), PHP_URL_SCHEME ) );
   setcookie( TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, '/nextcore-media-support/', 
   COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure );
   setcookie( 'LETMEIN', 'OK', 0, '/', COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure );

if ( SITECOOKIEPATH != COOKIEPATH ){

setcookie( TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, '/nextcore-media-support/', 
   COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure );
   setcookie( 'LETMEIN', 'OK', 0, '/', COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure );

}

}

Comment: You have to edit some part requirement your project.